# How to parsing string of shopify pagination link according new pagination update?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I Have one string which contains the link of prev and next page link:

```
Link: "<https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{version}/products.json?page_info={next_page_info}&limit={limit}>; rel={next}, <https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{version}/products.json?page_info={prev_page_info}&limit={limit}>; rel={previous}"
```

expecting output

```
array(
    'next' => {next_page_info},
    'prev' => {prev_page_info}
);
```

link string has also some condition as below:

1. string has both next and prev link
2. string has only next link Output should be array('next' => '{next_page_info}' );
3. string has only prev link Output should be array('prev' => '{prev_page_info}');

Comment: @04FS I have no idea how to parse this kind of string that's why I am asking...

Comment: Well then you should probably start familiarizing yourself with regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

To return page_info for all types of URL.

```
public function parsePaginationLinkHeader ($headerLink) 
{

    $available_links = [];
    $links = explode(',', $headerLink);
    foreach ($links as $link){

        if (preg_match('/<(.*)>;\srel=\\"(.*)\\"/', $link, $matches)) {

            $query_str = parse_url($matches[1], PHP_URL_QUERY);
            parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
            $available_links[$matches[2]] = $query_params['page_info'];
        }
    }

    return $available_links;
}
```

Response Dump

```
array(2) {
["previous"]=>
string(143) "eyJwdWJsaXNoZWRfc3RhdHVzIjoicHVibGlzaGVkIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoicHJldiIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjM3NDc0NDA1NTgxNjQsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiJhbHBoYWJldCB0LXNoaXJ0In0"
["next"]=>
string(188) "eyJwdWJsaXNoZWRfc3RhdHVzIjoicHVibGlzaGVkIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjE1MjAyMzAzMzQ1NDgsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiJBc3ltbWV0cmljIEhpZ2ggV2Fpc3QgU2hvcnQgU2xlZXZlIFJlZCBQYXJ0eSBEcmVzcyJ9"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function I wrote   just send it the links text or the whole header info

```
 private function render_links($Link)
    {
        $combined_links = [];
        $links = explode(',', $Link);
        foreach ($links as $link){
            if (preg_match('#<(http(?:s)?:\/\/.*\.myshopify.com\/.*products.json\?.*)>;.*rel=\\"(.*)\\"#', $link, $matches)) {
                $combined_links[$matches[2]] = $matches[1];
            }
        }

        return $combined_links;

    }
```

it will return   the links like this  as array

> ```
> "previous":"limit=1&fields=id%2Cimages&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJwcmV2IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NDA5OTUyMjM5NjE5NSwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6InNmc2Rmc2YifQ",
> "next":"limit=1&fields=id%2Cimages&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NDA5OTUyMjM5NjE5NSwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6InNmc2Rmc2YifQ"
> ```

Comment: In my case the URL before the ? is always different. However,   
thanks for your efforts